# Formula for derivative of $F(x)=\int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)} f(x,t) dt$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

> Let $I$ and $J$ be intervalls, $\phi:I\rightarrow J$ and
> $\psi:I\rightarrow J$ differentiable functions and $f:I\times
>  J\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ continuously differentiable twice (in $C^2$).
>
> Find a formula for the derivative of $F(x)=\int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)}
>   f(x,t) dt$ with $x\in I$. Hint: Chain rule

My attempt:

I did following: We know that $\int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b)-F(a)$. So therefore,
\begin{align*}
\frac{dF(x)}{dx}&=\frac{d [F(\psi(x))-F(\phi(x))]}{dx}=f(\psi(x))\cdot \frac{d\psi(x)}{dx}-f(\phi(x))\cdot \frac{d\phi(x)}{dx}\\
&=f(\psi(x))\cdot\psi'(x)-f(\phi(x))\cdot \phi'(x)
\end{align*}
I'm pretty sure that's right for $\int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)}
  f(t) dt$, but I'm not sure if that's correct for $f(x,t)$. Any remarks?

Comment: Wikipedia has the answer: [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule#Alternative_proof_of_the_general_form_with_variable_limits,_using_the_chain_rule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $a\in J$ and $g(x,t) = \int_a^t f(x,t)$. Then, $\partial_2 g = f$ and :
$$\partial_1 g(x,t) = \int_a^t \partial_1f(x,t)\text dt$$
This can be checked because, $\partial_2f(x,t)$ is bounded on a compact neighborhood of $\{x\} \times [a,t]$ in $I\times J$. Then, we have, by the fundamental theorem of calculus :

$$F(x) = g(x,\psi(x)) - g(x,\phi (x))$$
and, by the chain rule :
\begin{align}
F'(x) &= \int_a^{\psi(x)}\partial_1 f(x,t)\text dt  + f(x,\psi(x)) - \int_a^{\phi(x)}\partial_1 f(x,t)\text dt - f(x,\phi(x)) \\
&= f(x,\psi(x)) -f(x,\phi(x)) + \int_{\phi(x)}^{\psi(x)} \partial_1f(x,t)\text dt 
\end{align}